# Set table position to top

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, positioning

```
some content
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
tabular content
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\chapter{new chapter}
```

The output is:

First page:

```
some content
```

Second page:

```
table centered vertically
```

Third page:

```
new chapter
```

The problem is that table is centered vertically although its position is set to top [t] and second page's content is only table. How to force it to set it really on top?

Comment: The optional arguments to `table` or `figure` aren't binding for LaTeX and changed if required. The `\chapter` creates a new page and flushes all floats using `\clearpage`. Apparently there is not enough material in 'some content' to fill the page where the table appears. Because the page only contains a float it is changed to a float page, i.e. `[p]`, which centers the table. You could move the `table` earlier in the code to place it on top of the previous page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If LaTeX doesn't find the way to put the table on top, it will keep the float until it finds a `\clearpage` command. In this case it's issued by `\chapter`. It's better to give more than one choice, [tp] should suffice.

It all depends on how much copy follows the table before the new chapter; if the `table` ends the chapter, there won't be many possibilities to place the float on top. Move the `table` environment back by some paragraphs, until it will be placed on top of the last page of the section.

Answer (score 32):

You could try

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
```

Even if the float is on a single page, thus vertically centered by default, setting the distance from the top to the first float on that page to zero will help:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

See [Vertical layout of float pages](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-vertposfp) for further explanation.

Comment: It helps! Thanks!