# Float positioned in the middle of an otherwise empty page

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set table position to top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/set-table-position-to-top)

My document (`book`) has text and floats. There is not enough text, so that all floats can be placed before the text finishes. Then pdfLaTeX puts the remaining float right in the middle of an otherwise empty page. This does not look good. Is there a way to position these floats at the top of the page instead in the middle? Placement specifiers are already given `[t]`. Also combinations of `[h,t,!,H]` don't help.

Comment: Have a look at [Set table position to top](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/set-table-position-to-top/19170#19170), and please tell us if it helped.

Comment: That worked!!!!

Comment: Great, so I close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

write into the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fps@figure{!htb}
\setlength\@fptop{0pt} 
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.6}% before: .5 
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15} % before: .2 
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.8}     % before: .7 
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.5}  % before: .3 
\setcounter{topnumber}{3} % before: 2 
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1} % before: 1 
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5} % before: 3
```