# Vertical alignment for tables

Tags: tables, spacing, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set table position to top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/set-table-position-to-top)
>   [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/how-to-place-a-float-at-the-top-of-a-floats-only-page)

I've got this problem... I tried with the search but I couldn't figure out!

I've got many tables one after each others, with nothing in the middle

```
\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
 my code here
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
  my code here
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Each table is so big that it automatically goes to a new page. The last one is smaller than the others, it goes to a new page but it is aligned in the middle of the page and I can't move from there to a top alignment!

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28556/5764), [Set table position to top](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19163/5764). Also see [Vertical layout of float pages](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=vertposfp) - part of the UK TeX FAQ.