# Problem of figure and algorithm being placed on the middle of a page instead of top

Tags: graphics, floats, vertical-alignment, algorithms

My last page of an article is similar to the one below. 
On the second column, the fig. 4 is not placed on the top and the algorithm is not placed just below the fig. 4. 
How can I fix this?  The figure and algorithm are not quite related so I don't want to put them in the same float. 
I believe that if I add text (or many lines of text) then it will work but I want to ensure they're not centered even when there is no text or litte text.

The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180394/figure-placed-on-a-separate-page-is-centered-and-not-on-top) work for figure but not the algorithm.

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcommand\cpair[2]{%
\begin{tabular}{LL}#1 & #2\end{tabular}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{a caption}
    \label{fig:a label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{a caption}
    \label{fig:a label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{a caption}
    \label{fig:a label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{a caption}
    \label{fig:a label}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Insertion-Sort køretid}\label{AlgRun}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{insertion-sort}{$A,n$}   \Comment \cpair{c_1}{n=0}
        \State $inversions = 0$         \Comment \cpair{c_1}{n=1}
        \State \textit{L}[0..\textit{n} - 1] be a new array.
        \For{q=0}{n-1}
            \State L[q] = A[q]
        \EndFor
        \For{j=1}{n-1}
            \State $key = L[j]$
            \State $i = j - 1$
            \While{$ i \geq 0$ \textbf{and} $L[i] > key$}
                \State L[ i + 1] = L[ i ]
                \State $j = i - 1$
                \State $inversions = inversions + 1$
            \EndWhile
            $L[i + 1] = key$
        \EndFor
        \Return{inversions}
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the IEEEtran document class](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) discusess balancing the columns of the last page in section XIV (page 16). It suggests some workarounds.

One of them it mentions is using `\enlargethispage` with a negative value.

In your sample document, putting something like `\enlargethispage{-0.2in}` anywhere prior to `\begin{algorithm}` seems to have the desired effect.

[image: balancing figures with IEEEtran]

Because your actual document probably uses different figures, etc., and is different in other ways, you may have to play around with different dimensions for the command, and different placements.