# Issue with vertical positioning of graphics/images in the document?

Tags: graphics, positioning

Entire code is here

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ,subcaption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{65pt}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{sol}
   {\emph{Solution:}
   }
   {
   \qed
   }
\specialcomment{com}{ \color{blue} \textbf{Comment:} }{\color{black}} %for instructor comments while grading
\NewEnviron{probscore}{\marginpar{ \color{blue} \tiny Problem Score: \BODY \color{black} }}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%





%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\lhead{Student}  %replace with your name
\rhead{MAT 4170 \\ Aug 30 2019 \\ HW 1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%






\begin{problem}{1} 
How do we know there are only six symmetries of the equilateral triangle? Prove that can be there no more.
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}
\\
\begin{figure}[t]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=8cm]{equilateraltrianglesymmetries.jpg}
   \caption{Our minimal list of six symmetries of a triangle (Is it a maximal list as well?)}
   \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

First, note the following six distinct symmetries of our equilateral triangle in Figure 1.  From this we can observe that there are \textit{at least} 6 symmetries.  Now, assume that we have a seventh symmetry that maps our original triangle ABC, to some new configuration of points A, B, and C.  Note that there are only six possible permutations of three distinct objects (a result obtained from combinatorial counting).  Hence, any seventh symmetry obtained must be by definition one of our original six symmetries.  
\end{sol}
\\
\\

\begin{problem}{2} 
What happens if you combine two of the six symmetries? Is the combination a new symmetry or equivalent to one of the original six? Prove your conjecture.
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}
Let $T_1, T_2$ be some distinct transformations of the plane.  By definition, a symmetry is a 1-1 transformation (i.e. an isometry) that maps a geometric figure to itself.  Since transformations are a special class of  function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$, the composition of two symmetries of functions are also symmetries, by extension from the notion that compositions of isometries are also isometries.  
\begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ABC.jpg}
    \caption{Original figure}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BAC.jpg}
   \caption{Rotate 120 degrees CW}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BCA.jpg}
   \caption{One vertical flip}
 \end{subfigure}

 \caption{The two operations here produced one of the original six, specifically the $4^{th}$ symmetry in Figure 1.}
 \label{fig:coffee3}
\end{figure}
\end{sol}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Segment in question is down here: it keeps popping up in the center of a whole new page when I'd like it immediately follow my solution for the corresponding problem.

```
\begin{sol}
Let $T_1, T_2$ be some distinct transformations of the plane.  By definition, a symmetry is a 1-1 transformation (i.e. an isometry) that maps a geometric figure to itself.  Since transformations are a special class of  function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$, the composition of two symmetries of functions are also symmetries, by extension from the notion that compositions of isometries are also isometries.  
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ABC.jpg}
     \caption{Original figure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BAC.jpg}
    \caption{Rotate 120 degrees CW}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BCA.jpg}
    \caption{One vertical flip}
  \end{subfigure}

  \caption{The two operations here produced one of the original six, specifically the $4^{th}$ symmetry in Figure 1.}
  \label{fig:coffee3}
\end{figure}
\end{sol}
```

Comment: For more information on the vertical position of loating elements such as `figure`, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19170/134144 and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-vertposfp

Comment: If you don't want your images to float (move around) but have them at a fixed position, don't use a floating environment like `figure`. If you want to keep the captions, you can use `\captionof{figure}` from the `caption` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you actually don't want your images to float away from where they were mentioned in the code. Following this assumption, I propose the following code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, environ,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Remove demo option in your real document.
\usepackage{caption} % Added for the captionsetup command
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{65pt}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{sol}
   {\emph{Solution:}
   }
   {
   \qed
   }


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\lhead{Student}  %replace with your name
\rhead{MAT 4170 \\ Aug 30 2019 \\ HW 1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{problem}{1} 
How do we know there are only six symmetries of the equilateral triangle? Prove that can be there no more.
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}



\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \centering
   \captionsetup{type=figure}
   \setlength\belowcaptionskip{10pt}
   \includegraphics[height=8cm]{equilateraltrianglesymmetries.jpg}
   \caption{Our minimal list of six symmetries of a triangle (Is it a maximal list as well?)}
   \label{fig:my_label}
\end{minipage}

First, note the following six distinct symmetries of our equilateral triangle in Figure 1.  From this we can observe that there are \textit{at least} 6 symmetries.  Now, assume that we have a seventh symmetry that maps our original triangle ABC, to some new configuration of points A, B, and C.  Note that there are only six possible permutations of three distinct objects (a result obtained from combinatorial counting).  Hence, any seventh symmetry obtained must be by definition one of our original six symmetries.  
\end{sol}

\bigskip

\begin{problem}{2} 
What happens if you combine two of the six symmetries? Is the combination a new symmetry or equivalent to one of the original six? Prove your conjecture.
\end{problem}

\begin{sol}
Let $T_1, T_2$ be some distinct transformations of the plane.  By definition, a symmetry is a 1-1 transformation (i.e. an isometry) that maps a geometric figure to itself.  Since transformations are a special class of  function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$, the composition of two symmetries of functions are also symmetries, by extension from the notion that compositions of isometries are also isometries.  

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \centering 
 \captionsetup{type=figure}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ABC.jpg}
    \caption{Original figure}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BAC.jpg}
   \caption{Rotate 120 degrees CW}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BCA.jpg}
   \caption{One vertical flip}
 \end{subfigure}

 \caption{The two operations here produced one of the original six, specifically the $4^{th}$ symmetry in Figure 1.}
 \label{fig:coffee3}
\end{minipage}
\end{sol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

As a sidenote: In order to avoid having to manually number the problems, you could define and use a new counter as follows:

```
\newcounter{myproblem}
\setcounter{myproblem}{1}
\newenvironment{problem}[1][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries \themyproblem.}\stepcounter{myproblem}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

Comment: how does the package you use work differently from the {figure} environment?

Comment: @mathematicmango: A `figure` environment can float (move away from the place where it ws used in the code). You can observe this with your figure in the first problem. Although you inserted it as part of the `sol` environment, the image ends up above the first problem. Positions of floating environments can be influenced by the optional arguments (See also here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)).

Comment: The second figure in your example code is vertically centered on the second page instead of being aligned to the top of the page because  floats that are alone on a page (without any text)  are by default vertically centered. (To overcome this see: [How to place a float at the top of a floats-only page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28556/134144)).

Comment: In my answer I assumed that you actually didn't want your images to float but wanted to insert them where they are used in the code. I have therefore removed the `figure` environment. To keep image and caption together (prevent page breaks between them) I have used the `minipage` environments. To keep the `\caption` and `\subcaption` commands, (normally, these are only allowed in floating environments), I have added `\captionsetup{type=figure}` from the `caption` package. The `\setlength\belowcaptionskip` command helps to get some space between the caption and the following text.

Comment: You might also find this quite interesting: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144)

Comment: thank you for all the help and insight